# Create a folder in AWS S3 bucket with current date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to create a directory with current date as the directory name and move files created on my local file system into this new directory.

The goal is to transfer files created everyday in local system into S3 with current date as directory name.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive "local_folder" s3://bucket/directory/
```

How can I add the current date to the directory name?

Comment: Just type it? Or are you asking how to write a script that will automatically insert the current date into the command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I am asking how to automatically add the current date into the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a script like:

```sh
DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
echo aws s3 cp --recursive "local_folder" s3://bucket/$DATE/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a script, I'd prefer to do:

```
DATE=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
BUCKET="bucket-name"
aws s3 cp --recursive "local_folder" s3://${BUCKET}/${DATE}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the one which worked is below

```
aws s3 cp filename s3://bucketName/data/date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')/
```